# How to use shared preferences with boolean , true and false

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have used the following code to hide a view with SharedPreferences, with `getVisibility` and `setVisibility`, adding VISIBLE and GONE. But I am now wanting to use the SharedPreferences with boolean true/false with CheckBox, with `setChecked`. Can anyone help me ?

```
if (btnsearch.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    btnsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();  
    editor.putBoolean("visibilitySearch", true).commit();
}
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly, i.e. what issue do you have with your code?

Comment: I have no issue with my code. This is just example. I wanting to add shared preferences with boolean for checkbox to setChecked.

Comment: Just think about it: you know how to get checkbox object, you know you can call `setChecked()` on it, you know how to get/set a boolean in SharedPreferences. Don't be afraid to experiment, you will get some errors, will fix them etc etc. but you will learn along the way. Then if your code still doesn't work as you expect, or you don't understand something, come back and ask a very specific question. Usually, this is not a good place to ask for code without showing an effort (eg. code you already have).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for getting boolean value using shared pref,

```
Boolean visibilitySearch= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("visibilitySearch", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way.

```
boolean shouldItBeVissible = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("visibilitySearch",default_value in case of key not found(true or false));
```